# Type-Casting in C from Float to Int results in wildly different number, why?

Tags: c, type-conversion, pow, exponent

INPUT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        printf("%i", (int)pow(10,10));
        
        return 0;
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
-2147483648
```

For some reason, `pow()` results in a `double` as opposed to an `int` when I run it(I am using `Pow()` because for some reason, exponents are not coded into C). Any reason as to why?

Comment: Do you know what is the maximum number `int` can store?

Comment: What is your goal?  instead of casting, can you just use .0 formatting in your printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value a 4-bytes integer could hold is ranged from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The result of 10^10 is 10,000,000,000, which exceeds the limit and the conversion overflows which gives unexpected results. That's all.

Comment: `and the integer overflows` Nothing overflows in the presented code.

Comment: @Rohan Bari Thank you! Size limits on variables completely slipped my mind

Comment: @KamilCuk `-2147483648` is an overflow.

Comment: @RohanBari No, a value is not an overflow.

Comment: The OP tried to print the value of 10^10 by typecasting it into an integer, which overflows.

Comment: No, there is no "overflow". What operation does "overflow"? In what sense?

Comment: @KamilCuk: The conversion of 10,000,000,000 to `int` overflows. The C standard does not define a specialized C meaning for “overflow,” so this is just the ordinary use referring to a result that will not fit in the destination format. C 2018 6.3.1.4 1 discusses the conversion of floating-point to integer and says “If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @RohanBari: The behavior of the conversion is not defined by the C standard, but the result we observe, −2,147,483,648, is not “unexpected” either. While we cannot rely on it in the absence of some specification saying it will be the result, it is a common, not surprising or wholly unexpected result. E.g., Intel instructions generally produce this for a floating-point to integer conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The cast to `(int)pow(...)` is converting a `double` value to an integer type. A `double` is one of real floating-point types available in C.

The rule about converting a floating-point type to an integer can be found [in C11 draft 6.3.1.4p4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p1), but on there is easier version on [cppreference real floatinf-integer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Real_floating-integer_conversions):

> A finite value of any real floating type can be implicitly converted
> to any integer type. Except where covered by boolean conversion above,
> the rules are:
>
> ```
> The fractional part is discarded (truncated towards zero).
> ```
>
> - If the resulting value can be represented by the target type, that value is used
> - otherwise, the behavior is undefined

Assuming you have a sane platform, your `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `INT_MAX=2147483647`. The result of `pow(10, 10)` is a `(double)10000000000.0` and it's fractional part is not representable in the destination integer type `(int)`. The behavior of your code is just [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).